# Change values of a vector

Tags: matlab

I have the following matlab code, but it doesn't work as intended:

```
r = y > 0 % logical check
r(r == 0) = -1 % set all zeros to minus one
```

Why doesn't it work like it is supposed to do?

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? What you want to get? and what do you get?

Comment: I don't think you can assign `-1` to a `logical` array. Try `r = (double(r) * 2) - 1;`.

Comment: @sgar91 you don't need to cast explicitly, `r*2` will cast to double for you. I agree with your solution and your reasoning, you should post it as the answer. But you can just write `r = (y>0)*2 -1`

Comment: Thank you, sgar91 and Dan. That's exactly what I wanted to achieve! But what does the *2 do in code r = (y>0)*2 -1?

Comment: That for the 1's will remain 1's, and will not decrement to zero.

Comment: @JimBoy.. Multiplying by 2 converts all the ones to `2`, So now the array contains `0` and `2` only. Then subtracting 1 from the array converts all zeros to `-1`, and all twos back to `1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A logical vector can contain only boolean values `1` or `0`. If any other value e.g. `-1` is assigned to an element of a logical vector, the value will be converted to one of the two possible values.

If you want to have other values in the vector, consider converting its data type.

In your current scenario, you may want to do something like this:

```
r = y > 0;
r = (double(r) * 2) - 1;
```

Or as suggested by @Dan in the comment, you can also do this directly:

`r = (y > 0) * 2 - 1;`